# Is there a graph with a single odd vertex?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

This question was on the slides in my Discrete Mathematics class and I was told to draw one. I do not think it is possible. Any ideas?

Comment: Not with any graph with finite number of vertices. For finite graphs, what is the sum of degree of all vertices?

Answer (score 4):

Use the Handshaking Lemma to deduce that any graph will have have an even number of vertices of odd degree: since
$$
\displaystyle \sum_{v \in V} \deg v = 2|E|
$$
then we have that the sum of all the degrees of the vertices is EVEN. Suppose a graph had an odd number of vertices of odd degree, then we would have a contradiction since we'd get $\sum_{v \in V} \deg v =$ some odd number. In particular, $1$ is odd, so there is NO graph with exactly one odd vertex.

Comment: makes perfect sense. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No. The magic words are ["Handshake Lemma"](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Handshake_Lemma)